# passing multiple closures as parameters to a function in swift

Tags: swift

So I am trying to pass two closures to a function which creates a subview. The main part of function that takes closures as arguments and calls them is as follows:

```
///goButton and cancelButton are class level variables

var goButton = UIButton(type: .system)

var cancelButton = UIButton(type: .system)


func addSubViewWithAction(_ titleString:String, _ button1Text:String, _ button2Text:String, closureYes:@escaping ()->(), closureNo:@escaping ()->()) {

goButton.actionHandle(controlEvents: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside,
                      ForAction:closureYes)

cancelButton.actionHandle(controlEvents: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside,
                          ForAction:closureNo)
}
```

here is how I am trying to call it.

```
addSubViewWithAction("Hide Penguin here?","Yes","Cancel", closureYes: switchPlayers, closureNo: deletePenquin)
```

The problem is that it calls the deletePenguin function for both the buttons and never calls the switchPlayers function.

here is how I am adding buttons to main view through subview

```
    //v here is a UIView object
    //Add all buttons and text to subView
    v.addSubview(titleField)
    v.addSubview(goButton)
    v.addSubview(cancelButton)
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 8

    //Add subView to main view
    window.addSubview(v)
```

Comment: Why are you allocating the buttons inside function? These buttons should be connected with outlet or globally declared.

Comment: I am making custom buttons to perform tasks and not to change scene hence I did not connect them to outlet.

Comment: first remove let keyword, an make it class level variable

Comment: did that, same problem persists, code in question is updated accordingly

Comment: Adding action to a button method is wrong, Correct one is `addTarget`. Make both closures global using `typedef` then in this function just keep reference of both and in button action use the reference for call back.

Comment: addTarget in swift takes selector and selectors cannot take closures, and I am passing closures in the arguments because I want AddSubViewWithAction to be able to call different functions each time I call it so I can reuse the whole function. Basically I want to call this function again with different function passed as closures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `actionHandle` somehow works statically, so it will overwrite any previous assignment with the most recent one.

You could do the following (no complete code solution here, only pseudo-code):

- Subclass UIButton
- Add an instance variable that holds the closure to be executed
- Add an instance (helper) func that acts as the target for your event and inside executes the closure above
- Create a func that takes the closure to be excecuted as a parameter. Inside,

  - Assign your instance variable with the provided closure
  - Call `addTarget(_:action:for:)` with your helper func as the target

If you want to support different `UIControlEvent`s, you'll have to improve those steps a little, maybe by using a dictionary that maps the event to the closure or so.